# Articles not displaying in Lightning Community

Tags: lightning-community, lightning-knowledge, topics

We are developing a Lightning Community which will be used only by authenticated users. We have also set up a knowledge base and have done all the steps in adding the knowledge articles to topics/data categories for them to show up within the community.

This worked fine in the beginning, but somewhere along the line the articles stopped showing up within the community (internally is fine).

Things I have tried:

- Checked the "Topics for Objects" setting was enabled for Knowledge
- Remade Data Categories and reassigned them to Topics
- Checked object access under profile (I'm using SysAdmin profile so this shouldn't be a issue)
- Deleted and replaced the components in the community

Curiously enough the articles show if you search the community for them, they just don't show up under their Topic or when using the case deflection component.

How can I get the knowledge articles to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an update regarding this question, I opened a case with salesforce regarding this and got a response that way. The issue was that our community was created with the language English (US) and at some point it was changed to English (UK), which salesforce counts as two separate languages with regards to showing Knowledge articles.

So for anyone with the same issue, check that your language is correct within the community and matches the language of the written articles.

Comment: Once you select the correct language, is there anything we need to do? or will the articles from that language will just show up automatically in the content management section?

Comment: Also, do the user would also have to change their personal language settings in the Org for this or the Community Language would just suffice?